# Intersection of polygonal chain with straight line and its complexity

Tags: graph, geometry, polygon, graph-theory, computational-geometry

Let Z be an (open or closed) traverse(polygonal chain) in the plane consisting of k line segments. How to edit Z, that for a given query straight line 'g' can be decided quickly (i.e, better than in Θ (k) time) whether g ∩ Z = ∅?

I tried to connect it somehow with some tree structures in order to find any solution...

Comment: What editing operations are allowed ?

Answer (score 1):

These two papers may help. Although the problem is hard to approximate, if you
are willing to accept O( log *n* ) performance, it is possible.

> Chaplick, Steven, Elad Cohen, and Gila Morgenstern. "Stabbing Polygonal Chains with Rays is Hard to Approximate." *CCCG*. 2013. [PDF download](http://cccg.ca/proceedings/2013/papers/paper_50.pdf).
>
> M.J. Katz, J.S.B. Mitchell, and Y. Nir. Orthogonal
> segment stabbing. *Computational Geometry*, 30(2):
> 197–205, 2005.